# error enablingTriggerId[5]: Tag references an unknown trigger in google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am working on google tag manager , where i am creating tags from google tag manager api
from
[developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/tags/create](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/tags/create)

While i run the code i a, geeting this error

> {   "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "enablingTriggerId[5]: Tag references an unknown trigger.\n",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "enablingTriggerId[5]: Tag references an unknown trigger.\n",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "badRequest"
> }
> ],
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"   } }

Can i know what i am doing wrong so i can correct

Thank you helping

Comment: Its not much to go on without seeing your code, but the error message would suggest that you pass in an Id for a firing trigger but that no trigger with that id actually exists.

Comment: yes correct i found the error , i was passing a different Id for firing trigger ,so when i did console log for trigger function  i got the acctual trigger Id , when i replaced the firing trigger id , it works 
thank you for helping me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes correct I found the error, I was passing a different Id for firing trigger, so when I did console log for trigger function, I got the actual trigger Id, when I replaced the firing trigger id, it works

Thank you for helping me @Eike Pierstorff

Comment: This is not answer on the question